# AngularJS/RequireJS with ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, ng-grid

My setup consists of AngularJS/RequireJS and I am trying to add ngGrid. For some reason when I try to add this (like I have done for many other files) the grid does not appear on the front end.

No errors appear in the console and according to the network tab (in Chrome dev tools) the angular-grid.js files are loaded in okay.

The set up looks like the following;

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'app/',
    paths:{
        'angular': '../assets/js/angular.min',
        'domReady': '../assets/js/domReady',
        'jQuery': '../assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.min',
        'angularGrid': '../assets/js/angular-grid',
    },
    shim:{
        'angular': {
            exports: 'angular'
        },
        'angularGrid':{
            deps: ['angular', 'jQuery'],
            exports: 'ngGrid'
        },
    },

});
```

The angularGrid is then included with require setup.

```
require([
    'require',
    'angular',
    'jQuery',
    'angularGrid',
], function(require, ng, $, ngGrid) {...
```

Controller looks like this;

```
define(['../../module'], function (controllers) {
        'use strict';

        $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                 {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                 {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                 {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                 {name: "Enos", age: 34}];
        $scope.gridOptions = { data: 'myData' };


        overviewController.$inject = ['$scope'];
        controllers.controller('overviewController', overviewController);

    }
);
```

Finally html page has this;

```
<div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
```

Why isn't the grid appearing?

Comment: Check [this article](http://www.u3n0.com/?p=112), it might be the same error.

Comment: @Goodzilla - great article, check my comment below.

Comment: I've had a look at both links and none of them seem to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Angular are you using? If v1.2+, you need the Route library too.

I found this guide really useful with getting Require and Angular to play nice:

```
https://github.com/pviraj/Loading-AngularJS-Within-A-RequireJS-Project
```

Comment: Why do I need to include the Angular Route library too? I cant see that anywhere in the prerequisites.